# Jquery Select2 Dropdown Multiple Select Styling

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have been looking into the Select2 library and want to use their multiple select dropdown lists with tags. Using this code...

```
<select id="STATE_OR_COUNTRY" name="STATE_OR_COUNTRY" multiple class="form-control select2-select" style="width:300px">
    <optgroup label="US State">
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
    </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Other">
            <option value="Something">Something</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

I get a box that allows me to select multiple entries but it seems to create a bullet list below and add values to them as they are selected. Is there a way to override this display?

[image]

Comment: Is there some JS or JQuery that writes the list? None of that HTML should write a list.

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/1933/

Comment: Hmm, that is exactly what I want it to look like. I guess it is worth mentioning that this is an ASP.NET project and I am using the select2 nuget package so there may be something going on behind the scenes

Comment: It is generating a 

<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" style="width: 300px;">...</span>